# Blinking cursor on input fields and blinking time/timeout

Tags: gui-design, input-fields, input-focus

What about the blinking time?

Should it blink eternally until the user interacts?

I see that on Firefox 117, the blink stops after some seconds whereas it doesn't on chromium browsers.
Is the timeout a webbrowser parameter?

is there a best practice for it?

[image: short blinking]

[image: long/infinite blinking]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertical blinking bar in input fields, or *"cursor"* (also *"caret"* but less common, although it's used in CSS) indicates where the next characters will be inserted. Its blinking behavior can serve as a visual cue to users, signaling that the field is active and ready for input.

Generally, the choice of whether the cursor should blink eternally or stop after a certain timeout is a **design decision made by browser developers**. This behavior comes from old computers where you actually had blinking blocks at the beginning of a prompt line (or inverted blocks if the cursor was over some text) and was invented and patented by [**Charles Kiesling**](https://www.startribune.com/obituaries/detail/13986254/).

Different browsers have different behaviors, as you've observed. This difference is usually due to the browser's design and not a [**W3C standard**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-4/#pointing-keyboard), which includes a lot about cursors and how to modify them, but blinking speed is not one of the options to modify since it's browser based. However, while the timeout can be considered a browser parameter, some systems allow for customization, as seen in these old [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4743/usingtermemulators-17348/index.html).

Now, AFAIK, there isn't a universally accepted best practice for cursor blinking behavior. However, a few considerations can guide the decision:

- **User Comfort:** Aim to minimize potential distractions for users. If the target audience is more likely to be distracted by a constantly blinking caret, consider implementing a timeout.
- **Consistency:** If you're developing a web application with custom input fields (using Canvas or WebGL, for instance), strive for consistent behavior across all fields and platforms.
- **Accessibility:** Ensure that blinking rates (if implemented) are not too rapid, as excessively fast blinking can be disturbing or even trigger photosensitive reactions in some users.